# CGImage (or UIImage) from a CALayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I have created a `CALayer`
 (I added several shapes to the layer, but ultimately, I have a single CALayer), and I am having a LOT of trouble adding it to a CGImage.  I have found some references to `[CALayer renderInContext:ctx]`, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this...

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.bounds.size);
[layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Latest docs state that all `UIGraphics*Context` functions are main thread only (so they aren't thread safe on any OS version). `CGBitmapContextCreate` is the thread-safe CoreGraphics function that `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` is built on top of.

Comment: Also from the docs:  Discussion
You should call this function only when a bitmap-based graphics context is the current graphics context. If the current context is nil or was not created by a call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, this function returns nil.

Comment: Bear in mind that Apple never finished writing renderInContext, the official docs (2013) still state that it doesn't support large parts of Quartz / CALayer rendering - I've had major problems with layers disappearing completely because of these Apple bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a bitmap graphics context and use `renderInContext:` to draw the layer into it. You now have the layer in an image.