# How do you get an UIImage from an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, uiimage, avfoundation, opengl-es-2.0, calayer

I have already tried this solution [CGImage (or UIImage) from a CALayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816527/cgimage-or-uiimage-from-a-calayer)

However I do not get anything.

Like the question says, I am trying to get an UIImage from the preview layer of the camera. I know I can either capture a still image or use the outputsamplebuffer but my session quality video is set to photo so either of these 2 aproaches are slow and will give me a big image.

So what I thought could work is to get the image directly from the preview layer, since this has exactly the size I need and the operations have already been made on it. I just dont know how to get this layer to draw into my context so that I can get it as an UIImage.

Perhaps another solution would be to use OpenGL to get this layer directly as a texture?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: on your preview CALayer is store a CIImage reference into contents property.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Apple from this [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014134):

> A: Starting from iOS 7, the UIView class provides a method
>   -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:, which lets you render a snapshot of the complete view hierarchy as visible onscreen into a
>   bitmap context. On iOS 6 and earlier, how to capture a view's drawing
>   contents depends on the underlying drawing technique. This new method
>   -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: enables you to capture the contents of the receiver view and its subviews to an image
>   regardless of the drawing techniques (for example UIKit, Quartz,
>   OpenGL ES, SpriteKit, AV Foundation, etc) in which the views are
>   rendered

In my experience regarding AVFoundation is not like that, if you use that method on view that host a preview layer you will only obtain the content of the view without the image of the preview layer. Using the  `-snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` will return a UIView that host a special layer. If you try to make an image from that view you won't see nothing.

The only solution I know are `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`. Each one has its own limit. The first one can't work simultaneously with a `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` acquisition, the latter makes the shutter noise.